# Microsoft CommonDialog Control for higher version of MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, common-dialog

I've been searching the web for answers but got no success to find the right thing to do. So this is my last resort.

We have an Access database (1997) and works perfectly in our old remote server. But when we migrated it to Windows 2012 Server and convert it to .accdb file format, the **CommonDialog** built-in method which opens a window for selecting a file is not working and error message pops up.

[image]

By that we are completely aware that some references are missing and we were right.

[image]

We searched the web and realized that we need to use the **Application.FileDialog** under **Microsoft Office x.0 Object Library** for higher version of MS Access. We implemented that for some of our VBA code that utilizes the **CommonDialog** and it worked.

But we are also thinking on how are we able to continue using the **CommonDialog** for higher version of Access just for the sake of not tweaking our VBA code?

If you have an idea about this, I would be glad to hear. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't that present in the [Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0 Common Controls](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10019) package?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth The system requirements stated just for
Windows 2000, Windows 2000 Advanced Server, Windows 2000 Professional Edition , Windows 2000 Server, Windows 98, Windows 98 Second Edition, Windows ME, Windows NT, Windows Server 2003, Windows XP, Windows XP Home Edition , Windows XP Media Center Edition, Windows XP Professional Edition, Windows XP Tablet PC Edition

Comment: It's certainly not supported, this tech is way too old, but neither is Office 97. That doesn't mean it won't work

Comment: You can find the dll in the old computer. To make it work you will have to register it on the new windows server.

Comment: @Sion.D.P if I may ask do you have any links on how I can register it in windows?

Comment: Just Goooogle for **Register COM dll** youl find tones of links :-)